# Trying to copy matching columns from one table to another table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables called 'Images' and 'ImagesMSCV'. Both these tables contain the two columns 'MicrosoftId' and 'ImageId'. Right now the tables look like...

```
        Images                            ImagesMSCV
MicrosoftId | ImageId               MicrosoftId | ImageId
   null         234                     467        234 
   null         172                     512        172 
   null         376                     327        376 
   etc          etc                     etc        etc
```

So I'm trying to copy the 'MicrosoftId' column from 'ImagesMSCV' into the same column in 'Images'. To do this, I wrote the following SQLite statement...

```
UPDATE Images
  SET MicrosoftId =
    (SELECT MicrosoftId FROM ImagesMSCV
     WHERE ImagesMSCV.ImageId = Images.ImageId);
```

...however when I run this statement, my database just crashes. I don't know what's wrong with it?

EDIT: Apparently the database just stops responding because the UPDATE is taking so long. Any idea how to improve performance?

Comment: `UPDATE Images
  SET MicrosoftId =
    (SELECT MicrosoftId FROM ImagesMSCV
     WHERE ImagesMSCV.ImageId = Images.ImageId) WHERE ImageId = 234` It should complete. If yes, then your query is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each row in the `Images` table, the database has to look up the corresponding row in the `ImagesMSCV` table. Each such lookup requires a full table scan, except when there is an index on that column:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx ON ImagesMSCV(ImageId);
```

Comment: May I ask why you downvoted my answer without leaving any comment? The question was a bit unclear at the beginning and my answer just show possible steps.